# Univalued Binary Tree - recursive approach error

Tags: python, tree

A binary tree is univalued if every node in the tree has the same value.
Return true if and only if the given tree is univalued.

I have used recursive approach where I am checking for left and right nodes of the root and appending it to arr. Finally I am checking the unique values of the array. But I am not getting the right answer for [2,2,2,5,2] as nodes to the binary tree. I know there is a simpler dfs approach but I want to know what is wrong with my code. Please help.

```
class Solution:
    def isUnivalTree(self, root: TreeNode) -> bool:
        if root == None:
            return False
        arr = []
        arr.append(root.val)
        self.isUnivalTree(root.left)
        self.isUnivalTree(root.right)
        return len(set(arr)) == 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is always going to return True (except for an empty tree), because `len(arr)` is always going to be 1 -- you only `append` one value to it. Realise that `arr` is a *local* variable to the function, so any recursive call will have its own version of `arr`.

It is a better practice to use the *return* value of the recursive calls in order to get the final result:

```
class Solution:
    def isUnivalTree(self, root: TreeNode) -> bool:
        return ((not root.left or root.val == root.left.val and self.isUnivalTree(root.left))
            and (not root.right or root.val == root.right.val and self.isUnivalTree(root.right)))
```

If, and only when, there are two different values in the tree, there must be a node that differs in value from one of its children.

Answer (score 0):

You make a list in **each** call, i.e. each time `isUnivalTree` is called you initialize a new list. You should either set a list to the instance of the class, pass the list to the method or change the approach:

```
class Solution:
    def isUnivalTree(self, root: TreeNode, arr=None) -> bool:
        if root == None:
            return False
        if arr is None:
            arr = []
        arr.append(root.val)
        self.isUnivalTree(root.left, arr=arr)
        self.isUnivalTree(root.right, arr=arr)
        return len(set(arr)) == 1
```